# jQuery - slashes replaced with blanks for no reason

Tags: jquery

I got a jquery code:

```
$('.image_thumb').click(function() {
 var big_image = $('.image_thumb').attr('src').replace('thumbs/','').replace('skin/','');
 alert(big_image);
   $('body').html('<div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height:100%; background-color: #000000; background: url("..'+big_image+'") center center no-repeat;"></div>'
);
});
```

When I click an .image_thumb element, it first shows an alert, which is "images/work/1/image.png". But when the div loads, the url value in background looks like this: "images work 1 image.png" - all slashes are replaced with blanks. Could someone please explain what the heck? :)) Thanx.

Funny, but the following code works perfectly:

```
    $('.image_thumb').click(function() {
 var big_image = $('.image_thumb').attr('src').replace('thumbs/','').replace('skin/','');
 alert(big_image);
   $('body').html('<div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height:100%; background-color: #000000;"><img src="'+big_image+'"></div>'
);
});
```

There is only one problem - that way I can't center the image (as I do not know the width and height), so I'm pretty much stuck with the first option.

Comment: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gRJRp/ slashes are removed when they are appended into the style attribute

Comment: @scrowler I would really love a solution if you could provide one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself and it was quite... um... silly:

```
$('.image_thumb').click(function() {
 var big_image = $('.image_thumb').attr('src').replace('thumbs/','');
 alert(big_image);
  $('body').html('<div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height:100%; background: url('+big_image+') #000000 center center no-repeat;"></div>'
);
});
```

The double quotes in background:url() were interfering for some reason.

The other thing is, I had to remove .replace('skin/','') and not use the .. in the url() and now it all works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to put all of those properties except for the `background-image` into a class, create a div, assign the class to it and set the `background-image` property, then replace the body element with it (this is not a good idea by the way):

**CSS:**

```
.newElement {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.image_thumb').click(function() {
    var big_image = $('.image_thumb').attr('src').replace('thumbs/','').replace('skin/','');
    alert(big_image);
    var newElement = $('<div></div>').addClass('newElement').css('background-image', 'url(../' + big_image + ')');
    $('body').replaceWith(newElement);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gRJRp/1/)

Comment: thanx for the idea, but for testing purposes I always prefer to keep all css in the element. When the code goes stable, I move the css to the separate file :)) So yes, technically I'll do that later, but the main problem was caused by me using the double quotes in background:url()

Comment: Yes strange that that was the cause of your problem - at least you solved it.